# How to covert two ListAPIViews that are different into a single ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a django project I am working on that needs a users and account model. I am using and integrating Django Rest Framework. I was initially using individual API generic views from DRF. I am thinking of converting the individual generic views into a view set. I was able to do it for the user model. I wan to convert the Account model views to a view set.

My issue is that I have two versions of the same ListAPIView for the profile model. The top View lists all of the accounts in the database and the second one list all the accounts for an idividual user based on the User__Username foreignkey in the Account model.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'username'

class AccountListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

class AccountUserListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('user', '_id', '_class')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(user_username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

It says that I can specifically define the properties of a view within the viewset but I want to define two versions of the ListAPIView for the single model. Is there a way to double define the same view in a single viewset.

I basically want to define both of my Account ListAPIViews in the same viewset. How should i go about doing that if it is possible??

Answer (score 0):

you can use the @action decorator to define.

```
class UserViewSet( mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
     """
        A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving users.
     """
   def list(self, request):
      queryset = User.objects.all()
      serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data)

   @acttion(method="get", details=False, serializer_class=AccountSerializer)
   def account_list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       queryset = User.objects.all()
       data = self.get_serializer_class().(instance=queryset, many=True).data
       return response.Response(data)
```

Comment: I dont want a list and retreive view with a account_list view. I am trying to figure out how to create an `AccountViewSet` with two views. 1 view that displays all of the accounts  and another account list view that is filtered similarly to the AccountUserListView in the first block of code. BOTH of the views I want to create are ListAPIView within the same set. one just has a different filtering on it.